# how to perform a query every 30 seconds in android?

Tags: android, timer, handler, runnable

i have a query that i want to perform it every 30 seconds and Log it to Logcat. i did this by handler and i did not get response.

here is my code:

```
runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            int i;
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM info";
                cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }

            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                do {
                    i = cursor.getCount();

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();

                if (i > count) {
                    count = i;
                    Log.i("COUNT", "" + count);
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000);
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
```

if anyone can help me i will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Best Way to Create a Timer will be to Use Timer class

```
Timer _Request_Trip_Timer = new Timer();
    _Request_Trip_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

          //your code here



        }
    }, 5, 1000);// First time start after 5 mili second and repead after 1 second
```